# Excell VBA Runtime Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write this code to assist in data analysis for my dissertation but i get this error at a particular line:

Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D & LastRow")

I'm new to VBA but i have tried all options to present the right syntax as can be in the code below.

```
Private Sub Timeframe()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Timeframe As New Collection
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim RankValue As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Item As Variant

    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    Debug.Print LastRow

    Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "Timeframe"

    Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Clear

    RowNumber = 1

    'Set RankValue = Sheet1.Range("D2:D")

    'Set RankValue = Sheet1.Range("D2:D & LastRow")

    'Set RankValue = Application.Workbooks("LoopCode2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D & LastRow")

    'Set RankValue = Application.Workbooks("LoopCode2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D")

    'Set RankValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D & LastRow")

    'Set RankValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D & LastRow")

    'Set RankValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D")

    'Set RankValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D & LastRow")

    'Set RankValue = Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D & LastRow")

    Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D & LastRow")


    For Each Cell In RankValue

        On Error Resume Next

        Timeframe.Add Item:=Cell.Value, Key:=CStr("Cell.Value")

        On Error GoTo 0

    Next Cell

    Debug.Print LastRow


    For Each Item In Timeframe

        RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

        Sheet1.Cells(RowNumber, 6) = Item.Value

    Next Item

    Set Timeframe = New Collection

End Sub
```

Grateful if you could assist me find what I'm doing wrong, and how can i fix  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line with this:

```
Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
```

The `("D2:D" & LastRow)` part builds an address, like D2:D45. `&` means concatenation

**Added after comments**
If you put this just before a failing statement, you will understand more:

```
Debug.Print "D2:D" & LastRow
Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
```

Press Ctrl+G to show the debug window. It will print the value of `"D2:D" & LastRow` which is expected to be a range. If LastRow is empty or contains a string value, your range will normally not be valid.

Comment: Please I used  'Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D")' and had the same error message.  In fact, the various combinations i have used already are shown in the code, please. Thanks,

Comment: Please, it is meant to be a concatenation. It has been used earlier in the code successfully, so i don't think that is the problem, please.

Comment: You're right Sam, I used 'Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & LastRow)'  and it went through successfully without the error message.

Comment: ou're right Sam, I used 'Set RankValue = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & LastRow)'  and it went through successfully without the error message.  But somehow, the next step did not go through successfully - that's only the first data item was added to the Collection.  I'm investigating that to ensure that it has no relation with the changed line.  Please, is there a reason why 'Range("D2:D")' and 'Range("D2:D & LastRow")' produce that error message?  i think the data has not been selected into the collection as expected. I'm also not sure the syntax for the next step is fully accurate. Working on it

Comment: I have added some more to the answer

Comment: You're very correct. 'Debug.Print RankValue' just after the 'Set' line gave the exact number of data entries. The rest is up to me now. Thank you very much